# Nested findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, findviewbyid

I have this problem accessing TextView inside Relative Layout inside LinearLayout

Let's say I have these views in the file row.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" />
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/a_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/a">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/b_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/b">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to change the value of TextViews from an activity

```
LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout temp=(LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
((TextView)temp.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("This is title");
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)temp.findViewById(R.id.a_parent);
((TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.a)).setText("an this is the content of a");
```

I can successfully set the TextView of id 'title', but an error appears when approaching the last line. It says that the error was caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Can anyone tell me what is wrong, how to fix it, and why does the code not work as I expected?

Thanks

Comment: Please post all of the LogCat errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Exception is a ResourcesNotFoundException for a String.  Are you setting the value of the TextView using `getString`?  And if so, are you sure that this string exists in your strings.xml file?  If not, did you maybe reference one of your views with `R.string.name` instead of `R.id.name`?  It looks like you modified your code for posting, it may be easier to help if you posted exactly what you're doing in the original, as well as the full stack trace.

Sometimes problems with Resources occur because the R file isn't up to date with new code.  I would also try Rebuilding/Cleaning your project and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error comes when you are trying to set the integer value in Textview
 like below :

```
   textview.setText(1);
```

In this case the android will think that the integer value as string resource id and checks for
 the string the strings.xml and throws Resources$NotFoundException.
Please check your code. If not post your necessary code and logcat output.

Comment: Thanks, this is not obvious if you aren't paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
   LinearLayout temp=(LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.row....
```

in Your XML file, LinearLayout has not "android:id" property is declared.